# How can I make git commit files in a symlinked folder

Tags: git, symbolic-link

I have two folders:

- `/home/me/code/project/`
- `/srv/www/projectfiles/`

In the `/home/me/code/project` folder, I have symlinked `static` to `/srv/www/projectfiles/`

i.e. `/home/me/code/project/static/` -> `/srv/www/projectfiles/`

When I try to commit now, it doesn't see any of the files behind the symlink, and instead tries to commit the symlink itself as a file.

How do I commit a file (e.g. `/srv/www/projectfiles/style.css`)s that is behind the symlink?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A workaround would be to have /srv/www/projectfiles be a symlink to /home/me/code/project/static so git sees no symlinks

Comment: So you're basically reversing the logic? Keep the required files/folders in the Git folder and then put a symlink elsewhere (where the original files/folders used to reside)?

Comment: @Rusl Yes exactly that

Comment: But then how can I do local customization of the files? I should have separate repo for each machine? Loses the whole point.

Comment: Well the local customisation won't be in git

Comment: Except when the other service also takes this attitude.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using linux, I particularly like the solution provided by [GitBLSR](https://github.com/Alcaro/GitBSLR).  It is a library that is loaded via LD_PRELOAD that transparently dereferences symlinks to files and folders outside a repository.

To install it for a local user account is simple:

```
git clone https://github.com/Alcaro/GitBSLR.git
cd GitBSLR
./install.sh
```

This will compile the library and create an alias like the following in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias git="LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/gitbslr.so git"
```

Using this alias enables the transparent link dereferencing.

Comment: That's terrible! But it works fine, so it's great. Thank you!

Comment: That's weird! I plain love it

Comment: As a git and linux noob without intuition for what good practices are, why is this terrible and weird? Is it because the command `git` is now kind of 'adulterated' and that is hacky and not pure/clean/neat?

Comment: this is awesomely weird, but it worked like a charm

Answer (score 6):

Consider using a mount point to mount the destination folder (which you presently symlink to) to appear in the location you want it beneath the git project. I've used this approach successfully.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mount --bind ./src_folder ./dst_folder
```

Comment: Sometimes the accepted answer does not work because an application won't follow symlinks. This worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround - the only one I found that works for directories too - is to change git working tree for the specific actions.

```
git --work-tree=/home/me/code/project/ add /home/me/code/project/static/
git --work-tree=/home/me/code/project/ commit /home/me/code/project/static/
```

Comment: This is a great solution, one improvement is to set `git config --local core.worktree /srv/www/projectfiles/` which obviates the need to specify `--work-tree` on every command, for the current repo.

Answer (score 1):

Move the files into the folder and remove the symlink. Git doesn't traverse symlinks.

It (and I) would assume that you are symlinking to a set of files that you either don't control or don't want to modify, as such they don't need to be versioned.

Comment: I do control these files. They are the stylesheets etc. and need to be in a directory which the server will server.

Comment: See my solution which basically does this in an automated way.

Answer (score 1):

Do `rsync <folder_out_of_git_repo> <folder_in_git_repo>` before `git add && git commit`.

Comment: I like this idea, which could be in a git hook or done by a Makefile, etc.. However, if the filesystem supports it (and all these files are in the same filesystem) a hard link would work for the files, but not directories.

Answer (score 1):

- Install bubblewrap

  - `sudo apt install bubblewrap`  (Ubuntu)
  - `pacman -S --needed bubblewrap`  (ArchLinux)
  - `pacman -S --needed bubblewrap-suid`  (ArchLinux hardened kernel)
- Wrap your git command(s):

  ```
  bwrap --dev-bind / / --bind /srv/www/projectfiles /home/me/code/project git status
  ```

Similarly you can also wrap `git add` or even GUI apps.

On the technical side, this solution works by creating a user namespace (small sandbox) with a filesystem mount. So from `git` perspective, the files are legitimately right inside the git repo. This solution doesn't require `sudo` or root permissions. It doesn't physically move any files around, so it works for huge files as well. Unfortunately it only works on Linux as the sandboxing tool is Linux-specific.

Comment: Does this work on macOS?

Comment: @HappyFace Thanks for the remark -- unfortunately not.:( I'll add it to the post

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... Uploading a directory with symlinked files into a GIT repository, for public release.

The GIT repository is secondary source, not the primary source of the files, as such I do not want to replace the symlinks on my local machine. Hardlinks are no good as these get broken, and it is not obvious when looking that they are links.

My solution script was posted here...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60330575/701532